# mockito 3, what is the replacement of the nullable nayMap()?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

Having a class with a function:

```
class NetworkAPI {

    String executePost(Context context, String url, @Nullable Map<String, String> headers, String data) throws HttpConnectionException {
...
    }


private synchronized static void createInstance(@NonNull Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new NetworkAPI(context);
        }
    }

    static void init(@NonNull Context context) {
        createInstance(context);
    }

    public static NetworkAPI getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

and the test was working before with mockito-core 1x,

but when change to mockito-core 3.8.0 it fails at where it passes in `anyMap()`, get `error: incompatible types: Map<Object,Object> cannot be converted to Map<String,String>`:

```
@Test
    public void run_net_post() throws Exception {
        ......
        NetworkAPI networkApi = spy(NetworkAPI.getInstance());
        ......

        verify(networkApi).executePost(any(Context.class), anyString(), 
             anyMap(),   //error: incompatible types: Map<Object,Object> cannot be converted to Map<String,String>
             anyString()); 
        ......
    }
```

Can it still use this `anyMap()` for the required `@Nullable Map<String, String>` in mockito 3x, or it has to change to some other?

Answer (score 0):

found it works with `(Map<String,String>)nullable(Map.class)`
not sure if there is better alternative.